# PHP can't open uploaded files

Tags: php, web, ubuntu-12.04, lampp

I have Ubuntu Server with lamp.
When i uploading files like xls or images it works fine, but when I trying to open it says me that the Excel file was broken. Same thing happens with images

Is it possible that php changes the file?
Permissions for /var/www/publick_html/uploads is 777

Comment: please post some code relevant to the upload process

Comment: How are you uploading and storing the file? It's very difficult to help without code.

Comment: `$file = $_FILES['record']['tmp_name'] `

Comment: PHP doesnt change the file, but you may not have a file, have you checked the file size isn't 0?  Everynow and again you might get corruptions, but this should only happen rarely.

Comment: I can see and download this new uploaded files via ftp. But i can't open them from Excel or open images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in versions of apache and php.
Version of apache was 2.2 and php was 5.4
I upgraded my apache to 2.4 version and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

well, I know,I use windows and maybe this is extremely OFF TOPIC, but I have a simililar problem with uploaded files and my experience can be usefull for other people.

In my case, the uploaded file can not be open because it was written first in 
C:\Windows\Temp
and then moved to the upload directory, but my temp folder doesn t have permission to access to it. Infact, if I click on temp folder I see:

[image]

After I clicked "Continue", the problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem with being unable to open uploaded files with PHP on SQL SERVER. It solved mine.

You may come across the following problem using PHP on Microsoft IIS: getting permission denied errors from the move_uploaded_file function even when all the folder permissions seem correct. I had to set the following to get it to work:

1. Write permissions on the the folder through the IIS management console.
2. Write permissions to IUSR_'server' in the folder's security settings.
3. Write permissions to "Domain Users" in the folder's security settings.

The third setting was required because my application itself lives in a secure folder - using authentication (either Basic or Windows Integrated) to identify the users. When the uploads happen IIS seems to be checking that these users have write access to the folder, not just whether the web server (IUSR_'server') has access.

Also, remember to set "Execute Permissions" to "None" in the IIS management console, so that people can't upload a script file and then run it. (Other checks of the uploaded file are recommended as well but 'Execute None' is a good start.)

reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php